# IiPhone 5s won't appear in iTunes (appears in my computer) after iTunes update

Tags: itunes, iphone

I'm running Windows 10, and I recently updated my iTunes to the most recent version. Ever since then, my iPhone doesn't appear in iTunes. However, it still appears in my computer under "Apple iPhone" (rather than the actual name that I named it). Also, everytime I plug it in, it continually asks me to allow the computer to access my photos and videos.

Any ideas to how I can get iTunes to recognise it? (I really want to avoid doing a full reinstall of iTunes though.)

Answer (score 1):

I hope one of these will help you:

Have you given it permission to access photos and videos?
Try open apple software update on your PC, and check for another update.
Try restart your iPhone.
Try restart your PC.
Try with another lightning cable.

Comment: none of these worked unfortunately

Comment: Can you try with another lightning cable?

Answer (score -2):

maybe you will need to... because there might be a bug in the new version of itunes... so its better to uninstall and reinstall it again... i hope it recognises